# Controller test doesn't provide any request path to filter

Tags: spring-boot

I'm writing tests for my controller. In my application every request goes through filter but with exclusion for some requests:

```java
@Component
//@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE-10)
public class FilterTokenValidator extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    ...

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        return path.startsWith("/signup") || path.startsWith("/signin");
    }

    ...

}
```

On standardly ran application everything works great but when I run tests...

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ControllerSign.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= ToucanApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerSignTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private ServiceSign serviceSign;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private RepositoryNote repositoryNote;

    @MockBean
    private RepositoryUser repositoryUser;

    @BeforeEach
    void printApplicationContext() {
        Arrays.stream(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames())
                .map(name -> applicationContext.getBean(name).getClass().getName())
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Test
    public void createUser_valuesOK_statusOK() throws Exception {
        //todo check out possibility of create object and call method in same expression
        JwtUtil jwtUtil = new JwtUtil();

        when(serviceSign.createUser(eq("user1"), eq("user1")))
                .thenReturn(jwtUtil.generateToken(new EntityUser("user1", "user1")));

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/signup")
                        .contentType("application/json")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new DtoUsernamePassword("user1", "user1")))
        ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


}
```

...filter doesn't get any path (eg. using request.getServletPath() in doFilterInternal() method) and everything is wrong. Is there any better way for make something like exclusions in filter? Is some mistake in my controller test? Thanks so much.

Comment: You want the path n to the servlet path. Use `getRequestUri` instead of `getServletPath`.

Comment: Thank you. Test passed. It was a next little mistake like wrong import...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the annotation *@AutoConfigureMockMvc* does not mock the method *request.getServletPath()*.

In order to get over it, you can create a RequestPostProcessor which sets the servlet path value from the request uri and the context path:

```
public class ContextPathRequestPostProcessor implements RequestPostProcessor {

  private final String contextPath;

  public ContextPathRequestPostProcessor(final String contextPath) {
    this.contextPath = contextPath;
  }

  public ContextPathRequestPostProcessor() {
    this("");
  }

  public ContextPathRequestPostProcessor(final ServerProperties serverProperties) {
    this(serverProperties.getServlet().getContextPath());
  }

  @Override
  public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(final MockHttpServletRequest request) {

    this.setContextPath(request, this.contextPath);
    this.setServletPath(request, this.contextPath);

    return request;
  }

  private void setContextPath(final MockHttpServletRequest request, final String contextPath) {
    if (StringUtils.hasText(contextPath)) {
      Assert.isTrue(contextPath.startsWith("/"), "Context path must start with a '/'");
      Assert.isTrue(!contextPath.endsWith("/"), "Context path must not end with a '/'");
    }
    request.setContextPath(contextPath);
  }

  private void setServletPath(final MockHttpServletRequest request, final String contextPath) {

    Assert.isTrue(request.getRequestURI().contains(contextPath), "Requested uri must contains the context path");

    final var servletPath = request.getRequestURI().replace(contextPath, "");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(servletPath)) {
      Assert.isTrue(servletPath.startsWith("/"), "Servlet path must start with a '/'");
      Assert.isTrue(!servletPath.endsWith("/"), "Servlet path must not end with a '/'");
    }
    request.setServletPath(servletPath);
  }

}
```

And then add it to your test request:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/signup")
   .with(new ContextPathRequestPostProcessor())
   .contentType("application/json")
   .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new toUsernamePassword("user1", user1"))))
 .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Notice that ContextPathRequestPostProcessor constructor admits setting the context path or the ServerProperties (to retrieve the contextPath).